# How to use stencil component in react.js?

Tags: reactjs, stenciljs

I am having stencil web components for button, Im trying to use in react its click event  is not working, but its working fine in angular.
I have found many solution which used addEventListner but its not possible when I use dynamically. Please help me with solution other than addEventListner.

stencil component

```
import { Component, Prop, Event, EventEmitter } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
    tag: 'stencil-button',
    styleUrl: 'style.scss',
    shadow: true
})

export class StencilButton {
    @Prop() label: string;
    @Prop() primary: boolean;
    @Prop() secondary: boolean;
    @Prop() transparent: boolean;

    @Event() handleSubmit: EventEmitter;

    onSubmit() {
        this.handleSubmit.emit();
    }

    render() {
        return <button class={{ 'stencil-button': true,'stencil-button--primary': this.primary, 'stencil-button--secondary': this.secondary, 'stencil-button--transparent': this.transparent,  }}  onClick={() => this.onSubmit()}>{this.label}</button>
    }
}
```

React

```
<stencil-button handle-submit={() => { buttonClick() }} primary label='Submit'></stencil-button
```

here execpt click rest is working

Comment: Did you add the [React bindings](https://stenciljs.com/docs/react#bindings)?

Comment: Try following [this guide](https://stenciljs.com/docs/react)

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to stencil component's event by following way in react app:

```
<stencil-button onHandleSubmit={this.buttonClick} primary label='Submit'></stencil-button>
```

make sure to have **buttonClick** method present in your code.